# Help with a definition in Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups

Tags: representation-theory

I understand this lead up:

> An element $a$ of $GL(V)$ is, by definition, a linear mapping of $V$
>   into $V$ which has an inverse $a^{-1}$; this inverse is linear.
>
> When $V$ has a finite basis ($e_i$) of $n$ elements, each linear map
>   $a: V   \rightarrow V$ is defined by a square matrix ($a_{i,j}$) of
>   order $n$. The coefficients $a_{i,j}$ are complex numbers;

I'm getting tripped up here at:

> they are obtained by expressing the images $a(e_j)$ in terms of the
>   basis ($e_i$):
>
> $a(e_j) = \sum_i a_{i,j}e_i$

I don't understand this notation for "expressing the coefficients." This phrasing seems weird for what I understand the notation to be describing. I think of $a$ as the same thing as $T$ when we talk about linear transforms.

So, if I have a linear map described by the square matrix $a = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 \\
    2      & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$

with standard basis $
e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1    \\
    0       
\end{bmatrix},
e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0    \\
    1       
\end{bmatrix}$

Then $a(e_1) = 1e_1 + 2e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1    \\
    2       
\end{bmatrix}$

Am I understanding this correctly? It is giving me the first column of the matrix representing my linear map?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. $a(e_j)$ will be the $j$th column of the matrix $a$, and the $i$th entry of the $j$th column, $a_{i,j}$ will be the coefficient of $e_i$ when you write $a(e_j)$ in terms of the basis $\{e_k\}$.

Comment: Yup! I get it now. I personally think the paragraph has poor choice of notation; it gets really confusing with all the $a$'s representing something different in the same paragraph.

Comment: That's fair, you get used to it though.